# Office addin published failed because incomplete content "Authorizations" in "WebapplicationInfo"

Tags: manifest, office-addins, office-store

A week ago(7.9) we was publishing our office addin, and we uploaded our addin successfully. Today(7.16) we want to upload the same addin but get the follow error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlvNH.png)

If we added the "Authorizations" node at the Visual Studio, VS won't take that element and it would display error message to state that it is an invalid child element. Please see screen shot [image]
So it looks like that there is no "Authorizations" attribute in the "WebapplicationInfo" referencing this link https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/webapplicationinfo. and we are uploading the same add-in. Does anyone know more details to help us out?

Comment: Can you confirm it's an Outlook add-in you are trying to upload?

Comment: Thanks @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms, I am a colleague of Darren. yes, it is Outlook Add in. I edited the post to add error message at Visual Studio when we add Authorizations node under WebApplicationInfo although you might not see it right now since it is going through the peer review.  Basically it is not a valid element there and we are not sure why Seller Dashboard is complaining about it.  Thanks again and it is really appreciated for your help here.

Comment: by the way, @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms, there is another thread on this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438868/xml-schema-violation-office-add-in-manifests

Comment: We're looking into this now. I'll update once I know more.

Comment: cool, thanks @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms

Comment: We've rolled out a fix to address this issue. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: cool, thanks @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms

Comment: Hi, the SSO functionality is currently in preview which means it still needs finishing touches. Secondly SSO is not currently supported on Outlook Mobile and on-prem exchange clients. So can you let us know what scenario you hope to achieve by submitting to the store and have you implemented the fall back login mechanism (exchange identity token) as explained in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/implement-sso-in-outlook-add-in

Comment: oh, sorry, @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, there seems no notification to my email box and just saw the message. I would check with our team for this.