# XML Schema Violation Office Add-in manifests

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, office-store

I have an outlook add in manifest file.
I can upload it into my addin through Outlook online successfully.
However, when I upload to https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com I get this error message:

```
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link: https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
  - Details: The element 'WebApplicationInfo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Authorizations' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'.
```

When I use the validation tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest it returns the same errors.

This is my manifest file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At4sLIePWTrsfcX7-aCXraAhfSs

I try to validate 1 manifest file from OfficeDev but it is the same issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO/files/1241350/outlook-manifest.txt

[image]

I'm struggling with what my mistake is. Please advise.

Comment: here is another similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356390/office-addin-published-failed-because-incomplete-content-authorizations-in-we

Comment: We're looking into this now. I'll update once I know more.

Comment: We've rolled out a fix to address this issue. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Hi, the SSO functionality is currently in preview which means it still needs finishing touches. Secondly SSO is not currently supported on Outlook Mobile and on-prem exchange clients. So can you let us know what scenario you hope to achieve by submitting to the store and have you implemented the fall back login mechanism (exchange identity token) as explained in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/implement-sso-in-outlook-add-in